# Alternate field for autoincrement PK

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, rest

In my tables I use an auto-increment PK on tables where I store for example posts and comments.
I don't want to expose the PK to the HTTP client, however, I still use it internally in my API implementation to perform quick lookups.

When a user wants to retrieve a post by id, I want to have an alternate unique key on the table. 
I wonder what is the best (most common) way to use as type for this field.
The most obvious to me would be to use a UUID or GUID.
I wonder if there is a straightforward way to generate a random numeric key for this instead for performance.

What is your take on the best approach for this situation?

Comment: `UUID` and `GUID` are numbers, hence numeric. There is no "the best" absolute solution for anything. Why `GUID` (v4) wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @zerkms It can work for me. But I was a bit worried about performance as mentioned here: https://rclayton.silvrback.com/do-you-really-need-a-uuid-guid

Comment: You're not going to use it as a PK though. I'm not sure the performance paragraph is relevant for you (and I'm not sure it's 100% correct there).

Comment: @zerkms That's true. Currently I don't have an alternative, pure numeric solution for it, so I guess I'll go with the UUID. For users I use the Facebook id as public unique field, despite that it is currently a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a function that generates a 128-bit UUID, version 1 as described in RFC 4122, and returns it as a hex string with dashes, by the custom of UUID formatting.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

A true UUID is meant to be globally unique in space and time. Usually it's overkill unless you need a distributed set of independent servers to generate unique values without some central uniqueness validation, which could create a bottleneck.

MySQL also has a function `UUID_SHORT()` which generates a 64-bit numeric value. This does not conform with the RFC, but it might be useful for your case.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short

Read the description of the UUID_SHORT() implementation. Since the upper bits are seldom changing, and the lower bits are simply monotonically incrementing, it avoids the performance and fragmentation issues caused by inserting random UUID values into an index.

The UUID_SHORT value also fits in a MySQL `BIGINT UNSIGNED` without having to use `UNHEX()`.